# Find elements in array of objects that have same properties and create a new array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects like this:

```
arr = [
  { a: "dog", b: 8, c: "male", d: "big", e: 100 },
  { a: "dog1", b: 5, c: "female", d: "big", e: 200},
  { a: "dog2", b: 18, c: "female", d: "big", e: 350},
  { a: "dog2", b: 18, c: "female", d: "big", e: 350},
  { a: "dog", b: 3, c: "male", d: "big", e: 100 },
  { a: "dog", b: 8, c: "male", d: "big", e: 100 },
];
```

I want to create a new array containing only the property `a` and the sum of `e` of those objects that have the same values for `b`, `c` and `d`, so that I'll have and array like this:

```
arr2 = [
  { a: "dog", e: 300 },
  { a: "dog2", e: 700},
];
```

I've already tried to use a `map` function inside a `map` function looking for the elements that have the same properties `b`, `c` and `d`, then pushing the result in the `arr2`, but it pushes every time all the objects of my initial `arr`.

Comment: Probably looking for [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `Array.reduce` to create a map of the array elements, using b,c and d combined as the key.

Once we have this map, we can use `Object.values()` to get an array as the desired result.

```js
arr = [
  { a: 'dog', b: 8, c: 'male', d: 'big', e: 100 },
  { a: 'dog1', b: 5, c: 'female', d: 'big', e: 200},
  { a: 'dog2', b: 18, c: 'female', d: 'big', e: 350},
  { a: 'dog2', b: 18, c: 'female', d: 'big', e: 350},
  { a: 'dog', b: 3, c: 'male', d: 'big', e: 100 },
  { a: 'dog', b: 8, c: 'male', d: 'big', e: 100 },
];

const result = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    // Create a key from b,c,d..
    const key = cur.b + cur.c + cur.d
    acc[key] = acc[key] || { a: cur.a, e: 0 };
    acc[key].e += cur.e;
    return acc;
}, {}))

console.log('Result:', result);
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Universal solution for arbitrary array and keys to summarize

If you're looking for vanilla JS solution (no lodash), you may come up with something, adjustable to arbitrary group key property and property to summarize with [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

- build the [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/Map), having desired property as a key;
- increment `Map` items, based on the matching key
- get [`Map.prototype.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) of that `Map` into array

```js
const src = [
  { a: "dog", b: 8, c: "male", d: "big", e: 100 },
  { a: "dog1", b: 5, c: "female", d: "big", e: 200},
  { a: "dog2", b: 18, c: "female", d: "big", e: 350},
  { a: "dog2", b: 18, c: "female", d: "big", e: 350},
  { a: "dog", b: 3, c: "male", d: "big", e: 100 },
  { a: "dog", b: 8, c: "male", d: "big", e: 100 },
]

const summarizeValueByKey = (arr, key, val) => 
  [...arr
    .reduce((acc,{[key]: keyProp, [val]: valProp}) => {
      const group = acc.get(keyProp)
      group
        ? group[val] += valProp
        : acc.set(keyProp, {[key]: keyProp, [val]: valProp})
      return acc
    }, new Map)
    .values()]
    
console.log(summarizeValueByKey(src, 'a', 'e'))
```